# Using Postrgres JSON functions how to get an aggregated object of arrays

Tags: postgresql

Given a database schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.tags
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    tag_type text NOT NULL,
    name text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.tags_posts
(
    tag_id integer NOT NULL,
    post_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT tags_posts_pkey PRIMARY KEY (tag_id, post_id)
);

INSERT INTO tags (id, tag_type, name)
VALUES (1, 'typeA', 'tag1'), 
    (2, 'typeB', 'tag2'),
    (3, 'typeB', 'tag3'),
    (4, 'typeC', 'tag4'),
    (5, 'typeD', 'tag5');

INSERT INTO tags_posts (tag_id, post_id)
VALUES (1, 1),
    (2, 1),
    (4, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (3, 2),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 3),
    (2, 4),
    (4, 4),
    (4, 5),
    (5, 5);
```

I want to get a list of all tags with a json object of tags that are related through the tags_posts table, which would look like the following:

| name | tag_type | related |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tag1 | typeA | `{ 'typeB': [{name: 'tag2'}, {name: 'tag3'}], 'typeC': [{name: 'tag4'}] }` |
| tag2 | typeB | `{ 'typeA': [{name: 'tag1'}, 'typeC': [{name: 'tag4'}] }` |
| tag3 | typeB | `{ 'typeA': [{name: 'tag1'}] }` |
| tag4 | typeC | `{ 'typeA': [{name: 'tag1'}], 'typeB': [{name: 'tag2'}], 'typeC': [{name: 'tag5'}] }` |
| tag5 | typeD | `{ 'typeC': [{name: 'tag4'}] }` |

I feel like it should be possible, but I don't quite understand how postgres json functions work

Comment: Can you also add the insert / create table statements ?

Comment: Please clarify the question!

Comment: I have added the schema and insert staements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for

```
SELECT
  name,
  tag_type,
  (SELECT
    json_object_agg(
      tag_type,
      related_tags
    )
  FROM (SELECT
    rel.tag_type,
    json_agg(
      json_build_object('name', rel.name)
    ) AS related_tags
    FROM public.tags rel
    JOIN public.tags_posts l ON (rel.id = l.tag_id)
    JOIN public.tags_posts r ON (l.post_id = r.post_id)
    WHERE r.tag_id = t.id
      AND rel.tag_type <> t.tag_type
    GROUP BY rel.tag_type
  ) AS _
  ) AS related
FROM public.tags t
```

([Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2b2e10ba542badee38666f78c5fa244f))